# Java Using not extending from JFrame

Tags: java, object, jframe

I am having a hard time understanding how to write my program with out having it extend from `JFrame`.

I have tried removing the `extends JFrame` clause and and adding it into both my methods, replacing the `CalculatorWhichUsesAInterface frame = new CalculatorWhichUsesAInterface();` section with `JFrame frame = new JFrame();` and a few other things and nothing has worked.

How should I go about using `JFrame frame = new JFrame()` in my program instead of using `extends JFrame`?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class CalculatorWhichUsesAInterface extends JFrame{

     JFrame frame = new JFrame();

     public CalculatorWhichUsesAInterface(){
         JPanel jPanelOne = new JPanel();
         jPanelOne.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1);

         jPanelOne.add(new JButton("x"));

         JPanel jPanelTwo = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
         JTextField field = new JTextField();
         field.setText("2141987.01235");
         jPanelTwo.add(field, BorderLayout.NORTH);
         jPanelTwo.add(jPanelOne, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         add(jPanelTwo, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        CalculatorWhichUsesAInterface frame = new CalculatorWhichUsesAInterface();
        frame.setTitle("Calculator");
        frame.setSize(500, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually relativly easy (sorry, but it is).

Start by extending your class from `JPanel`, this provides you a basic container onto which to build your interface.

Remove the `JFrame frame = new JFrame();` as you're not really using it and in your `main` method, create a new instance of `JFrame` and add you component to it

```
class CalculatorWhichUsesAInterface extends JPanel {
     public CalculatorWhichUsesAInterface(){
        JPanel jPanelOne = new JPanel();
         jPanelOne.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1);


         jPanelOne.add(new JButton("x"));

         JPanel jPanelTwo = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
         JTextField field = new JTextField();
         field.setText("2141987.01235");
         jPanelTwo.add(field, BorderLayout.NORTH);
         jPanelTwo.add(jPanelOne, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         add(jPanelTwo, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                CalculatorWhichUsesAInterface calc = new CalculatorWhichUsesAInterface();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame()
                frame.setTitle("Calculator");
                frame.add(calc);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This concept provides you with a flexible and re-usable component.  This means that you can decide how and where the component is to be displayed.  Displayed on it's own in it's own frame (as the above example does) or added to another container (such as another `JPanel` or even an applet)

You may also want to take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

**Example two - not extending anything**
    class CalculatorWhichUsesAInterface {

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel jPanelOne = new JPanel();
                jPanelOne.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1);


                jPanelOne.add(new JButton("x"));

                JPanel jPanelTwo = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                JTextField field = new JTextField();
                field.setText("2141987.01235");
                jPanelTwo.add(field, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                jPanelTwo.add(jPanelOne, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame()
                frame.setTitle("Calculator");
                frame.add(jPanelTwo);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Updated with "builder" example**

This is a (very basic) example of a builder pattern, basically, you have a separate class which simply builds the UI and returns a `JPanel` (in this example)

More complex builders would allow you to add additional properties to adjust the outcome.

```
class CalculatorWhichUsesAInterface {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setTitle("Calculator");
                frame.add(CalculatorBuilder.build());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class CalculatorBuilder {

        public static JPanel build() {
            JPanel jPanelOne = new JPanel();
            jPanelOne.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

            jPanelOne.add(new JButton("x"));

            JPanel jPanelTwo = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            JTextField field = new JTextField();
            field.setText("2141987.01235");
            jPanelTwo.add(field, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            jPanelTwo.add(jPanelOne, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            return jPanelTwo;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I am having is that I need the program to run with out extending from any classes including JPanel.

Comment: You do realise that all classes extend from `Object` by default ;)  Second example...If all else fails, you could use a builder pattern

Comment: I do but i specifically have to keep the program completely separately from any other class's.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like everything you do in main (setTitle, setSize etc) you do for JFrame object that "comes" from inheritance (extends JFrame). So actually you are doing nothing with:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

If you want not to use inheritance, you should invoke methods of JFrame object, not the CalculatorWhichUsesAInterface(). So the constructor should look like this (in main leave only creating the object):

```
class CalculatorWhichUsesAInterface{
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     public CalculatorWhichUsesAInterface(){
         JPanel jPanelOne = new JPanel();
         jPanelOne.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1);


         jPanelOne.add(new JButton("x"));

         JPanel jPanelTwo = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
         JTextField field = new JTextField();
         field.setText("2141987.01235");
         jPanelTwo.add(field, BorderLayout.NORTH);
         jPanelTwo.add(jPanelOne, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         frame.add(jPanelTwo, BorderLayout.CENTER); //DIFFERENCE
         frame.setTitle("Calculator");
         frame.setSize(500, 200);
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setVisible(true);

     }
```

As you can see, I copied almost everyting from main to constructor, but it is invoked on different object (JFrame actually, not the CalculatorWhichUsesAInterface). But doing JFrame through inheritance is common way.

Comment: `BorderLayout.CENTER` is the default position if not specified (just saying) and (personally) I have an issue with a constructor creating a frame in this manner it reduces the re-usability of the class ... and you're still extending from `JFrame` ;)

Comment: Of course, I copied without removing "extends JFrame" part. I also do think that this is weird, I usually just extending JFrame

Comment: Extending from `JFrame` is not recommended. You're typically not adding any functionality or features to it and, if you build you UI directly to it, it locks you into a single use, making the class/project un-reusable.

Comment: This is working much better for me but I am still getting an error in the main method that frame is not being used.

Comment: Cause it is not used. You want to create JFrame and wait for user events. Some would write frame.setVisible(true) in main method, but I found it weird

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I'll keep that in mind. Extending from JFrame is what I was told by teachers on my first Java project.

Answer (score 1):

to not extend JFrame you have the right idea, but on your code above you'd need to first remove the extends JFrame but the way you declare your frame is fine:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
```

Then from there you just have to reference the object of it from then on, so for example:

```
frame.add(jPanelTwo,BorderLayout.CENTER)
```